# having a separated App.R file than one App.R file for R shiny, does it make faster?

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to make the Shiny Web faster. It normally takes about 2 minutes to launch the App.R file and open it in web browser. The origin App.R file contains a website that contains 3 tabs and each tab shows significant visualization.

I decided to have 3 different App.R files, seperating them by each tab. Therefore, each App.R file contains codes for each tab.

The logic comes here, instead having one App.R file that runs the code line by line, having 3 different App.R files will run the codes with a parallel process. I am asking this question to make sure that if the logic is right!

is there any other ways that we can make the server faster?

Comment: R doesn't run code in parallel. This would likely have no effect on speed. It would be better to have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092398/what-are-the-best-practices-to-make-shiny-application-run-faster) has some suggestions about this topic. According to the answer there, a dynamic ui (`renderUI`) can help with long loading times.