# Is it possible to parallelize DT::DataTable render in shiny?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

When data exceeds 300K rows, shiny rendering of `DT::DataTable` becomes slow because it is a single process. Any suggestions on making this process running in one or more processes?

The image below has only 178 rows, but showing the current shiny table might help.

I did some research and found some ideas, but did not now touch the render section

- [Code profiling for Shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484115/code-profiling-for-shiny-app)
- [What are the best practices to make shiny application run faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092398/what-are-the-best-practices-to-make-shiny-application-run-faster)

[image: Table]

Comment: Are you processing your DT on the server or on the client? See this [recommendation](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/80) for server-side processing with large tables

Comment: It is being used on the on the server-side, therefore I was wondering how to make use of several processes to help this out.